# How to chain "Single - Completeable - Completable" in rxkotlin?

Tags: android, rx-java2, reactivex, rx-kotlin

I am a beginner with rxjava/rxkotlin/rxandroid.

I need to deal with three diferent async-calls in a sequence.
The problem is that the first step returns a `Single<LocationResult>`, the second a `Completable`and the third again a `Completable`.

(Single -> Completable -> Completable)

The problem is now that the last `Completable` depends on the data of the first `Single`

My current solution:

I think this is a bad solution, but I don't know how to do this right.

```
val ft = FenceTransaction(applicationContext, apiClient)
        stream
            .flatMap { locationResult ->
                ft.removeAll()
                return@flatMap ft.commit().toSingle({ return@toSingle locationResult })
            }
            .flatMapCompletable {
                ft.recycle()
                ft.setZone(it.location.longitude, it.location.latitude, ZONE_RADIUS)
                val dots = DotFilter().getFilteredDots()
                for (dot in dots) {
                    ft.addDot(dot)
                }
                return@flatMapCompletable ft.commit()
            }
            .subscribeBy(
                onComplete = {
                    "transaction complete".logi(this)
                },
                onError = {
                    "transaction error".logi(this)
                })
```

Is this approch the correct way to do it?

And how should I dispose the `Completeables`?
Generally when should I dispose `Observables`?

Answer (score 1):

No idea if you still have this issue but generally for Single->Completable->Completable you'd do:

```
val disposable = service.getSingleResult()
                        .flatMapCompletable { locationResult ->
                            callReturningCompletable(locationResult)
                        }
                        .andThen { finalCompletableCall() }
                        .subscribe({...}, {...})
```

Comment: thx, but i asked how to get the result from the first single after the last completable

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun demo(): Completable {
    return Single
        .fromCallable {
            "lol" // original value from single
        }.flatMap { // "lol" become the param of this flatmap lambda
            Completable
                .fromCallable { Log.d("xxxx", "$it, completable 1") }
                .andThen(
                    Single.fromCallable { it } // `it` is "lol" we create a new single to continue pass the value downstream
                )
        }.flatMapCompletable { // "lol" again become the param of the lambda here
            if (it == "lol") { // we can now access the "lol" here
                Completable.fromCallable { Log.d("xxxx", " completable 2 HAPPY") }
            } else {
                Completable.fromCallable { Log.d("xxxx", " completable 2 SAD") }
            }
        }
}
```

Demo of `Single` -> `Completable` -> `Completable`, I think main thing is just to chain a `Single` after the first `Completable`, that returns the value of the original `Single`.

This will make the chain looks like:
`Single "value 1" -> Completable -> Single "value 1" -> Completabe`, this will make the the last clause `flatMapCompletable` access the original `value 1` and therefore we can decide which `Completable` to use at the very end.